# Read a CSV file in R, and select each element

Tags: r

Sorry if the title is confusing. I can import a CSV file into R, but once I would like to select one element by providing the row and col index. I got more than one elements. All I want is to use this imported csv as a data.frame, which I can select any columns, rows and single cells. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Here is the data:

```
SKU On  Off Duration(hr)    Sales
C010100100  2/13/2012   4/19/2012 17:00 1601    238
C010930200  5/3/2012    7/29/2012 0:00  2088    3
C011361100  2/13/2012   5/25/2012 22:29 2460    110
C012000204  8/13/2012   11/12/2012 11:00    2195    245
C012000205  8/13/2012   11/12/2012 0:00 2184    331
```

CODE:

```
Dat = read.table("Dat.csv",header=1,sep=',')
Dat[1,][1]  #This is close to what I need but is not exactly the same
         SKU
1 C010100100
Dat[1,1]    # Ideally, I want to have results only with C010100100
[1] C010100100
3861 Levels: B013591100 B024481100 B028710300 B038110800 B038140800 B038170900 B038260200 B038300700 B040580700 B040590200 B040600400 B040970200 ... YB11624Q1100
```

Thanks!

Comment: your data appears to be tab separated "\t" and not comma separated

Comment: You did get one element of the factor!

Comment: @timriffe: I resaved the data in CSV format, so I think they are comma separated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to character to get the value as a string, and no longer as a factor:

```
as.character(Dat[1,1])
```

You have just one element, but the factor contains all levels.

Alternatively, pass the option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to read.table when you read the file, to prevent creation of factors for character values:

```
Dat = read.table("Dat.csv",header=1,sep=',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that the only way? It seems like I need to convert all data into character and then do the selection?